# Automate Your Business Processes Workflow Rule Migration Map Your Workflow Criteria to Process Criteria

Tags: trailhead

I am doing Trailhead from the link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/automate_business_processes/modules/workflow_migration/units/workflow_migration_criteria .

From Setup, enter Builder in the Quick Find box, click Process Builder, and click New.

```
Configure the process’ properties.
    Name: New Cases
    Description: Automation for all cases on creation
    The process starts when: It’s invoked by another process

Configure the object node.
    Click Add Object.
    Select Case, and save the object node.
Click Add Criteria, and configure the Top Account criteria node.
    Name the criteria “Top Account”.
    For Field, select Top Account from the associated account.
        Click Find a field…
        Click Account ID > to select from the associated account’s fields.
        Enter Top, select Top Account, then click Choose.
    Selecting the Top Account field
    For Value, select True.
    Final configuration of Top Account’s conditions
    Save the criteria node.
Click Add Criteria, and configure the Basic Support criteria node.
    Name the criteria “Basic Support”.
    For Field, select Support Plan.
        Click Find a Field....
        Enter Support, select Support Plan, then click Choose.
    Selecting Support Plan in the Process Builder field picker
    For Value, select Basic.
    Final configuration of Basic Support conditions
    Save the criteria node.
Click Add Criteria, and configure the Premium Support criteria node. Do the same thing that you did for Basic Support, except name the criteria node “Premium Support” and select Premium for the filter condition’s value.
Click Add Criteria, and configure the Standard Support criteria node. Do the same thing that you did for Basic Support, except name the criteria node “Standard Support” and select Standard for the filter condition’s value.
```

All criteria nodes in the invocable process.

But when I tried 
[image]

***I would need to expect something like***

[image]

Comment: Top Account would be a field.  Can you confirm that such a field has been created under the Account Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Top Account"` is check box field you need to create on `"Account"`. 
`"Support Action"` is a picklist field you need to create on `"Case"` object with values `"Basic", "Premium", "Standard"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at earlier tasks to see if there was a field you needed to create under the Account object, called Top Account.  Create the field, and then try to reference it in Process Builder.